# Limit of a specific quotient involving exponentials

Tags: real-analysis

What is the limit as $h\rightarrow 0$ of
$$ \frac{he^{-h}}{e^{-2h}+3he^{-h}-1}$$

And how do you work it out (preferably without use of L'Hopital).

Depending on how I 'look at it' I get three different answers:

1. View $e^{-2h}-1$ (in the denominator) as being equal to 0 in the limit and answer is $1/3$
2. View $3he^{-h}$ as zero in the denominator and expand $e^{-2h}=1-2h+O(h^{2})$ so answer is $-1/2$
3. Same as 2. but keep the $3he^{-h}$ as it is and answer is $1$.

I think 3. is correct but can you provide a rigorous justification?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half-clever road: $\sinh h\sim h$ when $h\to0$ hence
$$
\frac{h\mathrm e^{-h}}{\mathrm e^{-2h}+3h\mathrm e^{-h}-1}=\frac{1}{3-2\cdot\left(\color{red}{\frac{\sinh h}{h}}\right)}\to\frac1{3-2\cdot\color{red}{1}}=1.
$$
Dumb (but sure) road: $\mathrm e^x=1+o(1)$ and $\mathrm e^x=1+x+o(x)$ when $x\to0$ hence
$$
\frac{h\mathrm e^{-h}}{\mathrm e^{-2h}+3h\mathrm e^{-h}-1}=\frac{h(1+o(1))}{(1-2h+o(h))+3h(1+o(1))-1}=\frac{h+o(h)}{h+o(h)}\to1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{he^{-h}}{e^{-2h}+3he^{-h}-1}=\frac h{e^{-h}+3h-e^h}=\frac1{3-\frac{e^{-h}-1}{-h}-\frac{e^h-1}h}$$

$$\text{Now, use } \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1$$

Comment: @Downvoter, sorry for misreading the Question

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that

> $$ \frac{he^{-h}}{e^{-2h}+3he^{-h}-1} = \frac{e^{-h}}{\frac{e^{-2h}-1}{h}+\frac{3he^{-h}}{h}}.$$

Now, you can distribute the limit. That is

> $$ \frac{\lim_{h\to 0}e^{-h}}{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-2h}-1}{h}+3\lim_{h\to 0}{e^{-h}}}. $$